# Is it possible to set quota for a network interface?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to set the quota for a network interface and reset if needed?

My intention is to block outbound network traffic from eth0 if the quota (say 500mb) is reached. And I should also be able to reset that if needed (maybe after some cooldown time).

Comment: You should be more clear. Is the quota for the whole system, for each local user on the system, for a source IP address routed by the system etc.

Comment: yes @A.B it is for the whole system. I checked iptables, there is a quota feature but I could not able to find how to reset that. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*iptables*'s [`quota`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#quota) match could have been used in a dedicated user chain to be able to reset it easily, but has been broken for a long time (I don't know if it's fixed): it resets whenever there are updates to unrelated rules. Strike this one.

You could use:

- [`quota2`](https://manpages.debian.org/xtables-addons-common/xtables-addons.8#quota2) from [xtables-addons](https://sourceforge.net/p/xtables-addons/xtables-addons/ci/master/tree/) providing additional *iptables* modules, which might require compilation (it's often automated, eg on Debian, installing xtables-addons-dkms would take care of it, but will pull a whole compilation suite, unless using special features like `dkms mkbmdeb` to build (on an other system) a .deb binary version). It has some interaction done through `/proc/net/xt_quota/` (reading to get the quota, or writing to reset it).
- embrace newer technology and use `quota` with *nftables*. When used in a *named* stateful object, it can be independently (from other similar objects) reset. Here's an example loosely adapted from [nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Stateful_objects#Referencing_stateful_objects_in_rules):

  ```
  nft add table inet quotahandling
  nft add quota inet quotahandling eth0output over 500 mbytes
  nft add chain inet quotahandling dropafterquota '{ type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept; }'
  nft add rule inet quotahandling dropafterquota oif eth0 quota name "eth0output" drop
  ```

  The *quota* will match (and thus proceed to execute *drop*) only when the defined quota is reached, all this limited to the *eth0* interface.

  You can list the quota with:

  ```
  # nft list quota inet quotahandling eth0output
  table inet quotahandling {
      quota eth0output {
          over 500 mbytes used 991177 bytes
      }
  }
  ```

  and atomically list-and-reset it with:

  ```
  nft reset quota inet quotahandling eth0output
  ```